# Exception handling in Bulk Copying to Amazon Redshift Using Avro files

Tags: json, exception, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, avro

I am trying to load avro files in S3 to a table in Redshift. one of the Avro files doesn't have a correct format. the problem is when copy command tries to load that file, it throws an exception and doesn't run the copy for correct files. how can I skip the wrong-formatted file and c
opy the correct files?  here is my code for loading file:

```
COPY tmp.table
FROM 's3://{BUCKET}/{PREFIX}'
IAM_ROLE '{ROLE}' 
FORMAT AVRO 's3://{BUCKET}/{AVRO_PATH}'
```

the error that I am getting is:

```
  code:      8001
  context:   Cannot init avro reader from s3 file Incorrect Avro container file magic number 
  query:     19308992
  location:  avropath_request.cpp:438
  process:   query0_125_19308992 [pid=23925]
```

Comment: Do you have any other files that start with the same prefix in that s3 bucket-prefix combo that are not avro? This is common problem when using something like Spark and not using manifest files for Redshift Copy.

Edit: after re-reading the question, I understand what you want to do and that is impossible. Redshift will try to process all files on the s3 path.

Comment: thanks @B.Pesevski for answering this question. no I don't have any other file with same prefix. what I did, was changing manually  one of the fields in avro file to be in different format from expected and I got this error

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the s3://{BUCKET}/{PREFIX} files and create a manifest file with only the Avro files that have the right format/schema. Redshift can't do this for you and will try to process all files on the s3://{BUCKET}/{PREFIX} path.